# Chrome auto rolagem da página para select multiple com opção selecionada

Tags: html, google-chrome, rolamento, html-select

Ao fazer uso do atributo `multiple`, a página ao ser carregada, faz rolagem para o último `<select/>` que contenha uma `option` com o atributo `selected`:

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/10zr45uk/)

```
<p>No Google Chrome a página não fica aqui...</p>
<form style="padding-top:1000px;">
    <p>No Google Chrome desliza para aqui...</p>
    <select multiple="multiple">
        <option selected="selected">1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

```css
form{
    padding-top:1000px;
}
```

```html
<p>No Google Chrome a página não fica aqui...</p>
<form>
    <p>No Google Chrome desliza para aqui...</p>
    <select multiple="multiple">
        <option selected="selected">1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Este mesmo problema encontra-se também reportado para o Chromium apesar que a indicação é que o mesmo surge apenas em algumas versões:

- [Issue 423256: Select elements cause automated scroll on page load](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423256)
- [Issue 426919: Page scrolls to select with multiple attribute on load if it contains a selected option.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=426919)

## Pergunta

Como contornar este problema de forma a que o website tenha o mesmo comportamento em todos os navegadores?

---

Testes onde o problema não se verifica:

- Chromium Version 37.0.2062.120 Built on Ubuntu 14.04, running on LinuxMint 17 (64-bit)
- Mozilla firefox 32.0.3 for Linux Mint - mint - 1.0
- Internet Explorer 11 - Versão 11.0.9600.17351 - Atualização 11.0.13 a correr em Windows 8.1

Reprodução do bug com sucesso:

- Google Chrome - Versão 38.0.2125.111 m a correr em Windows 8.1

Comment: Desculpe-me "ressuscitar" a questão, estava revendo algumas questões sem resposta e me deparei com a sua, eu não pude reproduzir o problema, me diga ele ainda ocorre? (versão 39) Outra coisa meu Windows é x64, o seu Windows está em uma maquina virtual (provavelmente x86)?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Fizeste bem, eu entretanto arranjei uma solução para ultrapassar o problema, terei que elaborar uma resposta com a mesma. À data de hoje, não sei se o problema ainda se verifica. Darei feedback tão cedo quanto possível sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 1):

À data de hoje, após atualização do navegador Google Chrome para a versão "39.0.2171.95 m" a correr em Windows 8.1 64Bit o problema já não se verifica.

Contúdo, na altura, para contornar o *bug* presente na versão indicada na pergunta e em outras conforme visto nos *bug reports* também indicados na pergunta, acabei por aplicar o seguinte [workaround](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workaround):

Ver exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/exobccnc/) <sup>funcional apenas em versões onde se note o bug</sup>

**JavaScript**

```js
// Quando o documento está pronto
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

        // ... outras ações primeiro ...


        var isChrome = window.chrome;    // identifica se é o Google Chrome
        if (isChrome) {                  // se for
            window.scrollTo(0,0);        // força o scroll para o topo da janela
        }
});
```

**jQuery**

```js
// Quando o documento está pronto
$(document).ready(function() {

    // ... outras ações primeiro ...


    var isChrome = window.chrome;    // identifica se é o Google Chrome
    if (isChrome) {                  // se for
        window.scrollTo(0,0);        // força o scroll para o topo da janela
    }
});
```